# Why did Solomon Lane still trust Ilsa?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, mission-impossible, mission-impossible-rogue-nation

Why does Solomon Lane still trust Ilsa after she helps Hunt in *Mission: Impossible - Rogue Nation*, lets him escape twice and even brings him an empty drive (which was supposed to contain the red box, of which Hunt's team still had a copy). Why doesn't Lane suspect her and kill her earlier? It seems to me that he put too much trust in her.

Answer (score 2):

I would say he knows how he can make sure Hunt does exactly what he wants. As we can see in the start of the movie, he kills the IMF agent at the record shop and Hunt chases him as he wanted.

He didn't trust Ilsa but used her to send a message to Hunt. He knew that he can catch her again (and he does) even if he gave her the task to convince Hunt to unlock the drive. and we can see he ordered his men to kill her once the drive was unlocked (as we see in end that Hunt gives him an account number to verify).

Answer (score 0):

I think he didn't trust her, he just tought she was under control after the failure with the empty drive (which wasn't her fault for being empty), with her being close to the bomb in Benij's body...

Also, this is a mission impossible movie, you should expect these kind of villains who thinks they can control everything agains the unkillable heros...

Comment: The drive being empty may not be directly her fault, but Lane tasked her with bringing the file. Wouldn't Lane take that as failing in the task?